# Is there a way in firestore to get full document path for documents retrieved using collection_group query in python?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I have a subcollection called schedule whose path is "/organization/{organization_doc}/team/{team_doc}/schedule/{schedule_doc}" and my collection group query is

```
db
    .collection_group(u'schedule')
    .where(u'active', u'==', True)
    .where(u'send', u'==', True)
    .stream()
```

I need to the get the document path for the documents retrieved using this query (ex:/organization/1UlA6MneaEnJO5BvTTtO/team/pcmR21Rc0ZdpacsY1tuC/schedule/mxDROVShx3Uo3FMN9Ohr).
I'm am able to get schedule_doc id(mxDROVShx3Uo3FMN9Ohr) using doc.id but I need the complete path which includes organization_doc id and team_doc id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're iterating the results of the stream, each [DocumentSnapshot](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentSnapshot) object will have a [reference](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) property which is a [DocumentReference](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference) object that contains the full [path](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference.path) of the document.

Answer (score 1):

Sure there is, but it's not well documented.

```
docs = db.collection_group(u'schedule')\
.where(u'active', u'==', True)\
.where(u'send', u'==', True)\
.stream()
for doc in docs:  
   path = doc.reference.path # this is a string
   print(path)
```